# How to recursively identify operators and arguments in an expression

Tags: regex, parsing, recursion

I have an expression like below;

```
abs(sum(Max(abs(ListInput)),Min(V1,V2)))
```

I want to take out operators which take single argument which is a symbol for a list of arguments , stored somewhere else.

For example in above case;

```
Max(abs(ListInput))
```

is what I need.

I am able to do it iteratively by tokenizing and converting the expression in to reverse polish notation.

But things break when operator is ternary.

```
IF(10 > Max(Abs(ListInput)),5,MAX(ListInput)) // (IF<EXPRESSION>,TRUEVALUE,FALSEVALUE) ; True value and Valse value can also be an expression.
```

I am trying to figure out to a recursive way to do this , but unable to think through all conditions.

Comment: Can't you use a recursive descent parser for this? It should be simple to implement using any parser generator, such as `bison`.

Comment: @barmar my goal is not to evaluate the expression , but just get those operators which have single input dependency.

Comment: is this a lisp like language?

Comment: @jgr208: It looks like a C-like language

Comment: Even reverse polish notation should be easily managable if you break a ternary operator into two binary ones. Can you show us your code, please?

Comment: I am writing in java. for expression IF(V_7> ABSSUM((MAX(V_8)),MIN(V_3,V_4)),5,V_10). RPN stack is as below. 
V_7
V_8
MAX
V_3
V_4
MIN
SUM
ABS
>
5
V_10
IF , I need to identify that MAX(V_8) which is an operator with list arguments

Comment: Ternary operator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681293/how-can-i-incorporate-ternary-operators-into-a-precedence-climbing-algorithm

Comment: @Bankelaal: Just let the `IF` pop three operands from the stack? Where exactly (in which step) is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to take out operators which take single argument which is a
>   symbol for a list of arguments … [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)

```
/(abs|sum|max|min)\([^(),]*(\([^(),]*\)[^(),]*)*\)/gi
```

[Online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/Ru2eco/1)